# How do you prevent blender from going off the memory cliff/singularity?

Tags: subdivision-surface

I often crash blender. I am pushing it to the limits of subdivision surface mod combined with subdivision edit mode. How do I stop losing my work due to crashes? Is there a setting that will warn me when I have introduced a giant computation that will take hours to perform? Maybe an addon? Mind you, I am running 3090 with latest Intel.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** You might start by asking yourself if you really need to be doing that. Subdividing in Edit Mode is a destructive edit. Sometimes it's necessary, but when possible you should find a way to get the same result using modifiers. And modifiers can be toggled off for the Viewport and left on only for renders. In addition to the drawback of a drop in Viewport performance, subdividing more than necessary will make your meshes hard to edit.

**2.** You probably don't need to be showing all objects in the 3D Viewport simultaneously. Consider hiding some objects and maybe even masking dense geometry on objects using the Mask Modifier.

**3.** **Save before doing any step that involves subdivision.** This is especially true if you are specifying the subdivision steps using a slider. It can be easy to overshoot with the slider and instantly send the poly count skyrocketing. Click the field and key in a value instead.

**4.** Keep watch on your total vert and face counts for your scene. Take note of approximately how high they can be at maximum without compromising stability - then try to keep them there.

Comment: Yup, the first point is by far the most important point of all!

Comment: Well. I was using a Displace modifier using a BW image, which needs tons of topo to look decent. You say I should use solely the Subsurf mod and no subdivide command? I was using both